# Jframe freezes when I press a button

Tags: java, swing

I'm in intro to Java so I only know the very basic of Java. I already searched for the answer but whenever I find someone with the same problem they have code that I don't understand. If someone could explain to me with as simple terms as you can that would be much appreciated. My problem is my Jframe freezes whenever I enter a my do while loop(at the bottom of my code). Through research I found out I should put a SwingWorker but I don't know how or where. Heres my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ATMSwingPanel extends JPanel
{
public  int count, Balance;
public String total, Input = "";
public JButton withdraw1,withdraw2,withdraw3,deposit,quit,num0,
num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,clear,enter;
public JLabel label, pinLabel, TextLabel;
public JTextField InputDisplay;

public ATMSwingPanel()

enter code here

{


    setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 6));;

    TextLabel = new JLabel("Please enter your pin");
    add(TextLabel);

    InputDisplay = new JTextField();
    InputDisplay.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


    withdraw1 = new JButton("Withdraw $20");
    withdraw1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    withdraw2 = new JButton("Withdraw $50");
    withdraw2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    withdraw3 = new JButton("Withdraw $100");
    withdraw3.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    deposit = new JButton("Deposit");
    deposit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    quit = new JButton("Quit");
    quit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num0 = new JButton("0");
    num0.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num1 = new JButton("1");
    num1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num2 = new JButton("2");
    num2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num3 = new JButton("3");
    num3.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num4 = new JButton("4");
    num4.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num5 = new JButton("5");
    num5.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num6 = new JButton("6");
    num6.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num7 = new JButton("7");
    num7.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num8 = new JButton("8");
    num8.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    num9 = new JButton("9");
    num9.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    clear = new JButton("Clear");
    clear.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    enter = new JButton("Enter");
    enter.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


    // Allows the labels and JButtons to appear when compiled


    add(TextLabel);
    add(InputDisplay);

    add(withdraw1);
    add(num1);
    add(num2);
    add(num3);

    add(withdraw2);
    add(num4);
    add(num5);
    add(num6);

    add(withdraw3);
    add(num7);
    add(num8);
    add(num9);

    add(deposit);
    add(num0);
    add(clear);
    add(enter);
    add(quit);

    // Background and window dimension sizes
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 300));


}
```

//  Represents a listener for button push (action) events.
   public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener

{
      //  Updates the counter and label when the button is pushed.
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            total= " ";

```
        Balance = 100;

        if(event.getSource() == num0)
        Input += "0";


        if(event.getSource() == num1)
        Input += "1";


        if(event.getSource() == num2)
        Input += "2";

        if(event.getSource() == num3)
        Input += "3";

        if(event.getSource() == num4)
        Input += "4";

        if(event.getSource() == num5)
        Input += "5";

        if(event.getSource() == num6)
        Input += "6";

        if(event.getSource() == num7)
        Input += "7";

        if(event.getSource() == num8)
        Input += "8";

        if(event.getSource() == num9)
        Input += "9";

        InputDisplay.setText(" " + Input);

        if(Input.equals("7777") && event.getSource() == enter)
        do
        {
        Input ="";
        TextLabel.setText("Your balance is " + Balance);

        }
        while ( event.getSource() != quit);

        TextLabel.setText("Goodbye.");


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread with `while ( event.getSource() != quit);`, this is not how event driven frameworks work, an event occurs, you respond, that's it.

The ETD is responsible for processing and dispatching events from the Event Queue, the `ActionListener` registered to your button is been notified by the ETD, but until the `actionPerformed` method exists, it can not continue processing the Event Queue, which makes you program appear to have "hung", cause it has.

Remove the `while` loop

Basically, you don't need the `while` loop, but an additional `if` statement to check for the `quit` button when `actionPerformed` is called

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your frame freezes is pretty simple: you block the event dispatching thread (all swing events at some point go through this thread), so you block the program from processing any other events, and thus the frame freezes. Since the while loop is an endlessloop (you only enter the while-loop, if the condition for looping is satisfied, and the result for `event.getSource()` won't change) your frame freezes.
For the `SwingWorker`:

```
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e){
    new SwingWorker<String , Object>(){
         public String doInBackground(){
              //create String for the label
              return labelText;
         }

         public void done(){
             TextLabel.setText(get());
         }
    }.execute();
}
```

would create and execute an `SwingWorker`, though this won't be necessary for an as simple and fast done task as yours. Just remove the endlessloop.