# Graphical Interface on Java Swing not working properly

Tags: java, swing

Help with Swing.
I come to you in time of great need, any help will be highly appreciated.

I have created a table game in java for a university project and now I must implement a graphical interface, we must use swing to do so.

The problem that I am facing here is that I am unable to run the actual game by simply adding a button and an action listener, the class that will actually run the game is the following,

```
package diagrammedeclasse;

import java.util.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.modeliosoft.modelio.javadesigner.annotations.objid;

import diagrammedeclasse.IdentityCard.Identity;
import diagrammedeclasse.RumourCard.rumour;

@objid ("ca5d80b7-7525-40a8-a35d-128867e0e079")
public class Player  {
    @objid ("db1ec2ea-ed45-4583-9835-29b566ac98e2")
    private String name;

    @objid ("956f1599-fada-4103-a41b-f39627d18dbe")
    private boolean isRevealed;

    @objid ("e023eaba-f6ba-4605-8d0e-7e7725d2cf0a")
    private int points;

    @objid ("88132cbd-f82b-4fa7-a075-3a43ad07ffdc")
    private boolean isWitch;

    @objid ("45b3c8e0-4313-4afe-9ed9-8df5132322e9")
    private boolean isVillager;
    
    private boolean isHuman;

    @objid ("fc187775-6ca3-4edb-a506-34fca14f59c0")
    private static int nombrejoueurs = 0;

    @objid ("f46be522-129a-43fb-b28f-ba42f46f4441")
    private int nbrebots;

    @objid ("d6656a4b-fc5f-4853-a503-892451396129")
    private static List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

    @objid ("09677697-75f5-4d0a-82af-16cb5ceb0e9f")
    private Strategy strategy;

    @objid ("733c2266-b1c2-46ed-ba09-cc9e5bc263a9")
    private Partie partie;

    @objid ("cf286f41-1aa5-4779-b094-b5f5b65bd2fe")
    private ArrayList<RumourCard> main;

    @objid ("21a4aa0a-ee12-4ad4-95b2-666a28109172")
    private ArrayList<RumourCard> carteJouee;

    @objid ("680477cf-5eee-4b60-9e4c-09e960c34158")
    public IdentityCard identityCard;
    private Player dernierjoueur;
    private int id;
    
    @objid ("49d924b4-d22c-42e6-b847-c388472720e5")
    public Player(String nom) {
        this.id=++Player.nombrejoueurs;
        this.carteJouee= new ArrayList<RumourCard>();
        this.name = nom;
        this.points=0;
        this.main=new ArrayList<RumourCard>();
        this.isVillager=false;
        this.isWitch=false;
        this.isHuman=true;
        this.isRevealed=false;
        this.identityCard=new IdentityCard(Identity.VILLAGER);
        this.partie=null;
        this.dernierjoueur=null;
        this.addPlayer(this);
            System.out.println("le joueur "+nom+" a ete cree");
            System.out.println("le joueur numero "+this.id);
    }
    public void addPlayer(Player p1) {
        Player.players.add(p1);
    }


    @objid ("bdef45fb-f512-412d-885a-36f4efe39d4a")
    public void ajouterBot() {
        System.out.println(Player.nombrejoueurs);
        int nbjou = Player.nombrejoueurs;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nombre de bots :");
        for(int i=0;i<=6-nbjou;i++) {
                  System.out.println(i);}
        nbrebots = sc.nextInt();
        int nbretotal = nbrebots + nbjou;
        if(nbretotal<3) {nbrebots=3-nbjou;}
        System.out.println("On ajoute " +nbrebots+" bots");
        Player.nombrejoueurs+=nbrebots;

    }
    

//pour name (get;set)
    @objid ("17536045-28a2-433f-9afa-fdd0734154f8")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @objid ("3c175d47-6b75-429b-85f3-438939129a8b")
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

//pour points (get;set)
    @objid ("c4617fa5-0e1b-4af3-8e83-af1d947e7381")
    public int getPoints() {
        return this.points;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    
    @objid ("b13f6fa2-3d52-4bb1-92dd-58993b0f1b3b")
    public Player choisirjoueur() {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choisissez un joueur :");
        int k=0;
        for(Player playe : this.partie.player) {
            if(playe.equals(this)) k++;
            else {
                System.out.println(k+1 +" : "+ playe.getName());
                k++;
            }
        }
               int selection = sc.nextInt();
               Player p1= partie.player.get(selection-1);
               System.out.println("joueur choisisser :"+p1.getName());
               return p1;
    }
    public Player choisirjoueuraccuser() {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choisissez un joueur :");
        int k=0;
        for(Player playe : this.partie.player) {
            if(playe.equals(this) || playe.isRevealed)k++;
            else {
                System.out.println(k+1 +" : "+ playe.getName());
                k++;
            }
        }
               int selection = sc.nextInt();
               Player p1= partie.player.get(selection-1);
               System.out.println("joueur choisisser :"+p1.getName());
               return p1;
    }

    public Player choisirjoueurautre() {
        Player playerx=null;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choisissez un joueur :");
        int k=0;
        for(Player playe : this.partie.player) {
            if(playe.equals(getdernierJoueur()) || playe.equals(this) || playe.isRevealed)k++;
            else {
                System.out.println(k+1 +" : "+ playe.getName());
                k++;
            }
        }
       
               int selection = sc.nextInt();
               System.out.println("joueur choisisser :"+ this.partie.player.get(selection-1).getName());
                playerx=  this.partie.player.get(selection-1);
               return playerx;
    }

    @objid ("25e6de92-3f5b-4843-8179-8c02f40b390b")
    public void chooseUsername() {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose a username :");
        String nom = sc.nextLine();
                this.setName(nom);
    }

  //methode pour choisir l'identite
    @objid ("c09b5791-ad90-4c49-b968-e838b203f08e")
    public void choisirIdentite() {
        int selection;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" Choose from these choices");
        System.out.println("1 - Witch");
        System.out.println("2 - Villager");
        selection = input.nextInt();
        if(selection==1) {
            this.setIdentite(Identity.WITCH);
        }
                if(selection==2) {
                    this.setIdentite(Identity.VILLAGER);
               }
    }
    //pour identityCard (get,set)
    @objid ("64524bab-e797-4b2c-8838-7826a384cf65")
    public void setIdentite(Identity newIdentity) {
        identityCard.setIdentity(newIdentity);
    }

    @objid ("551eee99-17db-4dcf-bbb3-0e927c9eabd8")
    public Identity getIdentite() {
        return identityCard.getIdentity();
    }

//methode pour reveler l'identite
    @objid ("638fdbf0-7639-40ab-9d5a-78f330080882")
    public void reveleridentite() {
        this.isRevealed = true;
        if (this.isWitch()) {
            Player p1=this;
        System.out.println(p1.getIdentite());
        this.partie.joueurHorsPartie(p1);
        }
        else {
        System.out.println(this.getIdentite());
    }
        }
    public void reveleridentitesecretly() {
        System.out.println(this.getIdentite());
    }
    
    public boolean revealedasVillager() {
        if(this.isRevealed() && this.isVillager()) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    
    public void prenercarteJouee() {
        if(this.carteJouee.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(this.getName()+" Ce joueur n'a pas des cartes jouer");
        }
        else {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choisissez une carte des cartes jouees :");
        int i=0;
          Iterator<RumourCard> it = this.carteJouee.iterator();
           while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i+1+" : "+it.next());  
            i++;
           }
               int selection = sc.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Card jouee :"+this.carteJouee.get(selection-1));
               this.main.add(this.carteJouee.get(selection-1));
               this.carteJouee.remove(selection-1);
               System.out.println("Cette carte a ete ajoute a ton main");
        }
    }

    public void prendrandomcartede(Player p1) {
        if(p1.main.size()==0) {
            System.out.println(p1.getName()+" n'a plus des cartes dans son main ");
        }
        else {
        Random random = new Random();
        int selection = random.nextInt(p1.main.size())+1;
        System.out.println("Choisissez une carte de :"+p1.getName());
               this.main.add(p1.main.get(selection-1));
               p1.main.remove(selection-1);
    }
    }

    @objid ("259b6cfd-b9c7-4e13-a815-36617fc647e3")
    public void prenerDiscardCard() {
        if(this.partie.getDiscardCards().size()==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Il n'y a pas des discards cards");
        }
        else {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choisissez une carte de Discard Card :");
       int i=0;
          Iterator<RumourCard> it = this.partie.getDiscardCards().iterator();
           while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i+1+" : "+it.next());  
           i++;
           }
               int selection = sc.nextInt();
               this.main.add(this.partie.getDiscardCards().get(selection-1));
               System.out.println("Cette carte a ete ajoute a ton main :"+this.partie.getDiscardCards().get(selection-1));
               this.partie.getDiscardCards().remove(this.partie.getDiscardCards().get(selection-1));
        }
    }

    @objid ("77cc019a-c10d-47e9-9e07-2c550955ac23")
    public void ajouterDiscardCard() {
        if(this.main.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(this.getName()+" a aucune carte dans son main");
        }else {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choisissez une carte de ton main :");
       int i=0;
          Iterator<RumourCard> it = this.main.iterator();
           while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i+1+" : "+it.next());  
           i++;
           }
               int selection = sc.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Discard card :"+this.main.get(selection-1));
               this.partie.getDiscardCards().add(this.main.get(selection-1));
               this.main.remove(this.main.get(selection-1));
    }
    }
    
    public void ajouterDiscardCard(RumourCard c1) {
        
               System.out.println("Discard card :"+c1.getRumourCard());
               this.partie.getDiscardCards().add(c1);
               this.main.remove(c1);
    }

    @objid ("c8fab12b-fd4d-400f-8999-022e719faf24")
    public void jouerCarte() {
        Player player1=this;
        int count=0;
        System.out.println("Choisissez une carte de ton main :");
          Iterator<RumourCard> it = this.main.iterator();
          int i =0 ;
           while(it.hasNext()) {
               RumourCard hey = it.next();
               if(!hey.jouablehunt(hey.getRumourCard(),player1)) count ++;
             System.out.println(i+1+" : "+hey);  
           i++;
           }
           if(count==main.size()) {
               System.out.println(player1.getName()+" a aucune carte qui peut etre jouer maintenant");
               System.out.println("il doit accuser un joueur");
               player1.accuse();
           }
           else {
           Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
               int selection = sc.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Card jouee :"+this.main.get(selection-1));
               RumourCard rm = this.main.get(selection-1);
               if(rm.jouablehunt(rm.getRumourCard(),player1))
               {
               this.carteJouee.add(rm);
               this.main.remove(rm);
               rm.useHunt( player1,rm.getRumourCard());
               }
               else 
               {
               System.out.println("Cette carte ne peut pas etre jouer maintenant");
            System.out.println("Choisir une autre carte de nouveau");
            player1.jouerCarte();
               }
               
           }
    }
    
    public void jouerCarteaccuser() {
        Player player1=this;
        int count=0;
       
        System.out.println("Choisissez une carte de ton main :");
        int i=0;
          Iterator<RumourCard> it = this.main.iterator();
           while(it.hasNext()) {
               RumourCard hey = it.next();
               if(!hey.jouablewitch(hey.getRumourCard(),player1)) count ++;
             System.out.println(i+1+" : "+hey);  
           i++;
           }
           if(count==main.size()) {
               System.out.println(player1.getName()+" a aucune carte qui peut etre jouer maintenant");
               System.out.println("il doit reveler son identite");
               player1.revelerIdentiteAfterAccusation(player1.getdernierJoueur());
           }
           else {
               Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
               int selection = sc.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Card jouee :"+this.main.get(selection-1));
               RumourCard rm = this.main.get(selection-1);
               if(rm.jouablewitch(rm.getRumourCard(),player1))
               {
               this.carteJouee.add(rm);
               this.main.remove(rm);
               rm.useWitch(player1,rm.getRumourCard());     
               }
               else 
               {
               System.out.println("Cette carte ne peut pas etre jouer maintenant");
            System.out.println("Choisir une autre carte de nouveau");
            player1.jouerCarte();
               }
               }
}


//pour isRevealed (get)
    @objid ("f1371808-24e7-4ce0-8b41-861cee45b646")
    public boolean isRevealed() {
        return this.isRevealed;
    }
    public void setisRevealed( boolean c1) {
       this.isRevealed=c1;
    }

//pour isWitch (get)
    @objid ("e5581073-0e3a-49d9-9a1f-290bbc480a37")
    public boolean isWitch() {
        return this.getIdentite() == Identity.WITCH;
    }
    
    public boolean isHuman() {
        return this.isHuman;
    }


   public void setHuman(boolean isHuman) {
    this.isHuman = isHuman;
}

//for isVillager (get)
    @objid ("0b3c7a19-052a-4490-8b36-101d73759ddc")
    public boolean isVillager() {
        return this.getIdentite() ==Identity.VILLAGER;
    }

//for main (get)
    @objid ("ca60f750-7879-4e5a-935f-933431e37748")
    public ArrayList<RumourCard> getMain() {
        return this.main;
    }


//for carteJouee (get)
    @objid ("95bb5134-0dcd-4c28-8171-0c57a80eb878")
    public ArrayList<RumourCard> getcarteJouee() {
        return this.carteJouee;
    }

//Methode pour ajouter des points
    @objid ("a264915c-9783-4165-b5f7-af5db30bf382")
    public void addPoints(int points) {
        this.points += points;
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" a gagner "+points+" points");
    }
    public void subPoints(int points) {
        this.points -= points;
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" a perdu "+points+" points");
    }
    
    public Partie getPartie() {
        return this.partie;
    }
    public void setPartie(Partie partie) {
        this.partie=partie;
    }

 public ArrayList<RumourCard> getDiscardedCards() {
     return this.partie.getDiscardCards();
     }


    @objid ("4fc9c966-d181-4d8c-a7d1-29e726f50c63")
    public void revelerIdentiteAfterAccusation(Player accuser) {
        Player p1 = this;
          this.reveleridentite();
          if (p1.isWitch()) {
              accuser.addPoints(1);
               accuser.jouer();
          } else {
              p1.jouer();
          }
    }
    
    
    public void accuse() {
        this.dernierJoueurs(this);
         joueraccuser(this);
    }
    public void accuseautre() {
        joueraccuserautre(this);
   }
    public void joueraccuserautre(Player accuser) {
        int k=0;
        for(Player playe : partie.player) {
            if(playe.equals(getdernierJoueur()) || playe.equals(accuser) || playe.isRevealed);
            else {
                k++;
            }
        }
        if(k==0) {
            System.out.println("C'est pas possible ");
            accuser.jouerCarte();
        }
            else {
        Player acc = accuser.choisirjoueurautre();
        if(acc.isHuman) {
        if(acc.main.size()==0) {
            System.out.println("Tu n'as plus des cartes Rumour");
            System.out.println("Tu doit reveler ton identite");
            acc.revelerIdentiteAfterAccusation(accuser);
        }
        else {
          Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Joueur ACCUSE "+acc.getName()+" 1 si tu veux jouer une carte WITCH  ou 2 si tu veux reveler ton identite");
              System.out.println(1+" : Jouer carte avec effet Witch");  
              System.out.println(2+" : Reveler identite"); 
                 int selection = sc.nextInt();
                 if(selection==1) {acc.jouerCarteaccuser(); }
                 if(selection==2) {acc.revelerIdentiteAfterAccusation(accuser);}
        }
    }else {
        Bots bot = (Bots)acc;
        bot.accuseautre(accuser, acc);
    }
        
            }
        }

    @objid ("58706d4b-9e70-4ce5-9720-b5da656527d5")
    public void joueraccuser(Player accuser) {

        Player acc = accuser.choisirjoueuraccuser();
        if(acc.isHuman) {
            if(acc.main.size()==0) {
                System.out.println("Tu n'as plus des cartes Rumour");
                System.out.println("Tu doit reveler ton identite");
                acc.revelerIdentiteAfterAccusation(accuser);
            }
        else {
              Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Joueur ACCUSE "+acc.getName()+" 1 si tu veux jouer une carte WITCH  ou 2 si tu veux reveler ton identite");
              System.out.println(1+" : Jouer carte avec effet Witch");  
              System.out.println(2+" : Reveler identite"); 
              int selection = sc.nextInt();
                 if(selection==1) {acc.jouerCarteaccuser(); }
                 if(selection==2) {acc.revelerIdentiteAfterAccusation(accuser);}
        }
        }
        else {
            Bots bot = (Bots)acc;
            bot.accuse(accuser, acc);
        }
    }

    @objid ("d24ef235-c674-4527-b040-c6f9a23b73e0")
    public void ajouterCarte(RumourCard card) {
        this.main.add(card);
    }

    public void jouer() {
        if(this.partie.partieTermier()) {
            System.out.println("Partie terminer");
            this.partie.afficherscore();
        }
        else {
            this.dernierJoueurs(this);
        System.out.println("C'est le tour de "+this.getName());
        if(this.main.size()==0) {
            System.out.println("Tu n'as plus des cartes Rumour");
            System.out.println("Tu doit accuser un autre joueur");
            this.accuse();
        }
        else {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choisisser 1 pour jouer une carte avec un effet hunt ou 2 pour accuser un autre joueur");
            System.out.println(1+" : Jouer carte avec effet Hunt");  
            System.out.println(2+" : Accuser un autre joueur"); 
            int selection = sc.nextInt();
           if(selection==1) {this.jouerCarte(); }
           if(selection==2) {this.accuse();}
        }
        }
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "" +name;
    }
    
    public String printPlayerCards() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(name + " has the following cards:\n");

        for (RumourCard card : main) {
            stringBuilder.append(card + "\n");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    public void dernierJoueurs(Player p1) {
        for(Player plx : players) {
            plx.dernierjoueur=p1;
        }
    }
    public Player getdernierJoueur() {
        return dernierjoueur;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Partie game = new Partie();
        Bots marc = new Bots("marc");
        Bots taha = new Bots("taha");
        Bots grg = new Bots("grg");
        Bots elissa = new Bots("elissa");
        Bots salim = new Bots("salim");
        while(!game.jeuterminer())
        {
        game.initialiser();
        game.ajouterJoueur(marc);
        game.ajouterJoueur(elissa);
        game.ajouterJoueur(grg);
        game.ajouterJoueur(taha);
        game.ajouterJoueur(salim);
        game.initialiserCarte();
        game.afficherscore();
        game.choisirIdentite();
        game.distribuerRumourCard();
        game.displayCardsForAllPlayers();
        game.commencerpar();
        }           
    }
}
```

The above is my code for the main engine, i didn't post the code for all the classes, but the game runs well on console side.

```
package diagrammedeclasse;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class interfacetest {

    private JFrame frame;
    private Player player;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    interfacetest window = new interfacetest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interfacetest() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1280, 720);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton bot4 = new JButton("New button");
        bot4.setBounds(245, 10, 164, 230);

        JButton bot3 = new JButton("New button");
        bot3.setBounds(193, 10, 164, 230);

        JButton bot2 = new JButton("New button");
        bot2.setBounds(139, 10, 164, 230);

        JButton bot1 = new JButton("New button");
        bot1.setBounds(87, 10, 164, 230);

        JButton bot0 = new JButton("New button");
        bot0.setBounds(31, 10, 164, 230);
        
        // getting the image of the angry mob card
                DeckImage angrymobcard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage angrymob = angrymobcard.getImage(0, 0);

                // getting the image of the inquisition card
                DeckImage inquisitioncard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage inquisition = inquisitioncard.getImage(0, 1);

                // getting the image of the pointed hat card
                DeckImage pointedhatcard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage pointedhat = pointedhatcard.getImage(0, 2);

                // getting the image of the hooked nose card
                DeckImage hookednosecard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage hookednose = hookednosecard.getImage(1, 0);

                // getting the image of the broomstick card
                DeckImage broomstickcard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage broomstick = broomstickcard.getImage(1, 1);

                // getting the image of the wart card
                DeckImage wartcard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage wart = wartcard.getImage(1, 2);
                // card5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(wart));

                // getting the image of the ducking stool card
                DeckImage duckingstoolcard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage duckingstool = duckingstoolcard.getImage(2, 0);
                // hon code el card.setIcon(new ImageIcon(duckingstool))

                // getting the image of the cauldron card
                DeckImage cauldroncard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage cauldron = cauldroncard.getImage(2, 1);

                // getting the image of the evil Eye card
                DeckImage evileyecard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage evileye = evileyecard.getImage(2, 2);

                // getting the image of the toad card
                DeckImage toadcard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage toad = toadcard.getImage(3, 0);

                // getting the image of the black cat card
                DeckImage blackcatcard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage blackcat = blackcatcard.getImage(3, 1);

                // getting the image of the pet newt card
                DeckImage petnewtcard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage petnewt = petnewtcard.getImage(3, 2);
                
                JButton card = new JButton("New button");
                card.setBounds(31, 437, 164, 230);
                
                JButton card1 = new JButton("New button");
                card1.setBounds(205, 437, 164, 230);
                
                JButton card2 = new JButton("New button");
                card2.setBounds(382, 437, 164, 230);
                
                JButton card3 = new JButton("New button");
                card3.setBounds(559, 437, 164, 230);
                
                JButton card4 = new JButton("New button");
                card4.setBounds(736, 437, 164, 230);
                

        JLabel welcometext = new JLabel("Welcome to Witch Hunt !");
        welcometext.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        welcometext.setBounds(205, 10, 409, 226);
        frame.getContentPane().add(welcometext);

        JButton exitbutton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitbutton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JButton startbutton = new JButton("Start");
        startbutton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // remove old stuff
                startbutton.setVisible(false);
                exitbutton.setVisible(false);
                welcometext.setVisible(false);

                // start the new game
                Partie game = new Partie();
                Bots marc = new Bots("marc");
                Bots taha = new Bots("taha");
                Bots grg = new Bots("grg");
                Bots elissa = new Bots("elissa");
                Bots salim = new Bots("salim");
                while(!game.jeuterminer())
                {
                game.initialiser();
                game.ajouterJoueur(marc);
                game.ajouterJoueur(elissa);
                game.ajouterJoueur(grg);
                game.ajouterJoueur(taha);
                game.ajouterJoueur(salim);
                game.initialiserCarte();
                game.afficherscore();
                game.choisirIdentite();
                game.distribuerRumourCard();
                game.displayCardsForAllPlayers();
                game.commencerpar();
                }
                // show the back of the other player cards
                DeckImage backcard = new DeckImage();
                BufferedImage back = backcard.getImage(0, 3);
                frame.getContentPane().add(bot4);
                frame.getContentPane().add(bot3);
                frame.getContentPane().add(bot2);
                frame.getContentPane().add(bot1);
                frame.getContentPane().add(bot0);
                bot4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(back));
                bot3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(back));
                bot2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(back));
                bot1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(back));
                bot0.setIcon(new ImageIcon(back));
                
                
                
                
                // create your cards
                frame.getContentPane().add(card);
                frame.getContentPane().add(card1);
                frame.getContentPane().add(card2);
                frame.getContentPane().add(card3);
                frame.getContentPane().add(card4);
                // show your cards
                ArrayList<JButton> bouton = new ArrayList<JButton>();
                bouton.add(card);
                bouton.add(card1);
                bouton.add(card2);
                bouton.add(card3);
                bouton.add(card4);

                player = player.getdernierJoueur();
                Iterator<RumourCard> it = player.getMain().iterator();
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        switch (it.next().getRumourCard()) {
                        case Angry_Mob:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(angrymob));
                            break;
                        case The_Inquisition:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(inquisition));
                            break;
                        case Pointed_Hat:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(pointedhat));
                            break;
                        case Hooked_Nose:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(hookednose));
                            break;
                        case Broomstick:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(broomstick));
                            break;
                        case Wart:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(wart));
                            break;
                        case Ducking_Stool:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(duckingstool));
                            break;
                        case Cauldron:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(cauldron));
                            break;
                        case Evil_eye:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(evileye));
                            break;
                        case Toad:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(toad));
                            break;
                        case Black_Cat:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(blackcat));
                            break;

                        case Pet_Newt:
                            bouton.get(i).setIcon(new ImageIcon(petnewt));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        startbutton.setBounds(10, 10, 185, 108);
        frame.getContentPane().add(startbutton);

        exitbutton.setBounds(10, 128, 185, 108);
        frame.getContentPane().add(exitbutton);

    }
}
```

Here is what i have tried to do in the graphical interface part so far, i got the images for the cards and thought of getting a start button that runs the main code of the game and when i do this, the game runs fine on console but the graphical interface freezes. I want to know if this is the right way or if there is another way to do it.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185485/java-swing-gui-freezes or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641537/jframe-freezes-when-i-press-a-button

Answer (score 0):

The GUI is likely freezing because you are running the game on the UI thread - the thread that handles the button click - and in the game, you are waiting on a scanner on System.in.

Getting the GUI "unstuck" is the easy part: Run your game module using a separate thread. The difficult part is going to be re-orienting your game so that it can be used from the GUI, rather than from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the help !!